Can you use Prime in order to treat businesses as nodes?
In Page 526-527 of Mage20 the book mentions how Primal Utility  (Prime) can be used to treat businesses as nodes. Does this require a mage to have the technocrat version of Prime or can any mage whose paradigm is appropriate for treating businesses as node do so regardless of their allegiance?

Technocrats only.
The alternate spheres are an optional rule for Technocracy games. On page 512 of the M20 core book, it says:

Optional Rule:
Technocratic Alternative Spheres
Three optional Spheres at the end of this section reflect the
Technocratic refinements of three of the nine mystic Spheres, as
presented in the Revised Convention Books for the New World Order (the
Data Sphere, an analog of Correspondence), the Syndicate (Primal
Utility, the hypereconomic applications of Prime), and the Void
Engineers (Dimensional Science, the scientific perspective on Spirit).
For the most part, these optional Spheres may be purchased ONLY by
Technocratic operatives, as these disciplines reflect the training,
research, and conditioning of the Technocratic Union. The exception,
Data, is based on innovations by the Virtual Adepts and has since been
adopted by technomancers from all over the spectrum.

Moreover, "a character cannot possess both a Technocratic Sphere and the corresponding mystic Sphere. Doing so would essentially reflect a divided perspective on Reality – believing two related yet opposed beliefs about the same thing."
So, you can't have both Primal Utility and Prime, and Primal Utility is only for Technocratic operatives -- in particular, the Syndicate and its "money = quintessence" paradigm. A character who truly has that view of the world may wish to consider using the rules on that page to change their sphere understanding from one to the other, effectively joining the Technocracy.
